# Number of unique outputs by substituting variables

Tags: combinatorics, fastest-algorithm

Given a set of formulas like this:

```
bacb
bcab
cbba
abbc
```

Give an algorithm that finds the number of unique results you can get when each variable is substituted for either "0" or "1" in every formula.

There are `(k!)^2` formulas, each with `2k-1` variables and `k^2` terms. Express your asymptotics in terms of `k`.

Fastest algorithm wins. In case of a tie the solution with lower asymptotic memory usage wins. If that's still a tie, first post wins.

---

For the example above the following results can be acquired by substituting the variables:

```
1110, 0110, 1001, 0100, 1000, 0000, 0010, 1101, 1111, 0001, 1011, 0111
```

So the correct answer is 12. Among others, `1010` can not be made using the above formulas.

I've made  three more tests cases, with respective solutions of [230](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/orlp/8c1190ef1fb31f45427d/raw/9495f614554ca2203a5d685fce4691488306dcee/small.txt), [12076](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/orlp/8c1190ef1fb31f45427d/raw/ba3cb8a9da05cbb4bf5a4d9287e194f8a3a384ec/big.txt) and [1446672](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/orlp/8c1190ef1fb31f45427d/raw/fc227c65f5dad86fb454d64e6c23caa3457ed315/huge.txt).

Comment: Clarification: what is k in the question? Is it just some abstract constant?

Comment: @isaacg Yes. It's to prevent ties between solutions that are faster for less but larger formulas, for example.

Comment: So each letter `a`,`b`,... is a *variable*? And we have always only an uneven number of variables? Doesn't it matter how long the sequence of variables is, and on how many *formulas* you are given?

Comment: @flawr The exact relation between the number of variables, number of terms and number of formulas is given in the question.

Comment: Does 'can be' mean that you can get *up to* $(k!)^2$ *formulas* or are there *exactly* $(k!)^2$ formulas? Besides that, do you have any application for an algorithm with those specifications? I'm just asking because the specs seem to be pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @flawr The figures are _exact_, I just meant that it could be for any positive integer $k$. And this is a subproblem I encountered while making an answer to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48745/count-the-number-of-hankelable-matrices), that I thought was interesting on its own.

Comment: This is a cool challenge. It took me a while to understand that the formulæ represent numbers.

Comment: I'm confused. What are the formulas? What are variables and terms?

Comment: @xnor In the example above there are 4 formulas (`bacb`, `bcab`, `cbba`, `abbc`). The first formula (`bacb`) has 4 terms, in order: `b`, `a`, `c`, `b`. All formulas have 3 variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: @orlp I see now, thanks. I believe counting 3-colorings reduces to this. So it's #P-hard. There won't be a polynomial time solution, thought different exponential ones can still compete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mathematica, O(k^2(k!)^2) time

```
Length[Union@@(Fold[Flatten[{StringReplace[#,#2->"0"],StringReplace[#,#2->"1"]}]&,#,Union[Characters[#]]]&/@#)]&
```

Hopefully I calculated the time complexity correctly. Input is a list of formulas such as `{"bacb","bcab","cbba","abbc"}`. Runs in less than 30 seconds for every test case on my machine, but who cares about absolute times?

#### Explanation:

- First off, the `&` at the end makes it a pure function, with `#` referring to the first argument, `#2` being the second argument, etc.
- `Length[*..*]` takes the length of the list contained inside it.
- `Union@@(*..*)` takes the contained list and supplies it as the arguments for `Union`, which returns a list of the unique elements in any of its arguments.
- `*..*&/@#` takes a pure function and maps it over the list of formulas, so that `{a,b,c}` becomes `{f[a],f[b],f[c]}`. Note that in nested pure functions, `#n` refers to its innermost arguments.
- `Fold[*..*&,#,*..*]` takes a accumulator function, starting value, and list, and returns `f[f[...[f[starting value,l_1],l_2],...],l_n]`.
- `Union[Characters[#]]` takes all the characters in the current formula and gets all the unique elements, giving us the variables.
- `Flatten[*..*]` flattens its argument, so that `{{{a},b},{{c,{d}}}}` becomes `{a,b,c,d}`.
- `{*..*,*..*}` is simply a way to combine the two results using the above `Flatten`.
- `StringReplace[#,#2->"0/1"]` takes the previous result and returns it with the current variable replaced with either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Why are you using `k` as the variable in your time? Still, factorial time! Phew!

Comment: The op said: "Express your asymptotics in terms of `k`." Also, I had to do a `GeneralUtilities\`Benchmark` for each method used.

Comment: Care to add a plain english description of your algorithm? I'm unfamiliar with Mathematica, so I can't verify your solution.